# Remove brackets created by a list through json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to connect to an API that is requesting the following input format:

```json
{
    "clientId":"some_client",
    "apiKey":"some_key",
    "requestTime":1620912445968,
    "sha":"some_sha",
    "owner":"owner@somewhere.com",
    "contacts": [
    {
      "addresseeType": "email",
      "value": "email1@test.pl, email2@test.pl"
    }
  ]
}
```

My issue with this is that the emails inside `"value"` end up with brackets when I use `json.dumps()` if my input is a list. My take on this is the following:

```py
# I need to take the emails from a pandas df
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ["dan@git.com", "me@git.com"]})

dict_params = {
        "clientId":"some_client",
        "apiKey":"some_key",
        "requestTime": "millis",
        "sha":"some_sha",
        "owner": "owner@somewhere.com",
        "contacts": [
            {
              "addresseeType": "email",
              "value": df["email"].to_list()
              }
            ]
        }

result = json.dumps(dict_params)
```

This gives a valid JSON as expected, but it's not what my API is asking for, as the emails must not have brackets.

The result:

```
{
  "clientId": "some_client",
  "apiKey": "some_key",
  "requestTime": "millis",
  "sha": "some_sha",
  "owner": "owner@somewhere.com",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "addresseeType": "email",
      "value": [
        "dan@git.com",
        "me@git.com"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated!! thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`', '.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
'value': ', '.join(df['email'])
```

e.g

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['dan@git.com', 'me@git.com']})
print(', '.join(df['email']))
# dan@git.com, me@git.com
```

Comment: Thank you @DeepSpace, It does work correctly. If you don't mind, can you explain what is `', '.join` doing here?

Comment: @DanielChavarría [`', '.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a link